# is there any way to find that a firewall is protecting a server and showing all ports closed in nmap?

Tags: wireshark, packet

I am using nmap to scan open ports on a device which uses FTP protocol to transfer firmware for update. But it is showing all 1000 ports are closed.

It comes with a software to update its firmware. When we connect device to computer and use ifconfig to list IP addresses connected with device, it shows new IP address which is used by that device. Using wireshark we can monitor all protocols used by that software and device to communicate with each other. But there is no mention of FTP protocol in wireshark output. only SSDP, LLDP and MDNS protocols are used. I want to know how that software is transferring data to device when all ports are closed (as shown in Nmap output). If ports are protected using firewall, is there any way to bypass that firewall? and how to identify that firewall first. Please help and if I missed some points which I must mention to explain my problem then please comment.

Link to wireshark output - [here](https://easyupload.io/n0v2ev)

Comment: Pcap instead of txt? What is the device? How do you know it uses FTP (you say that Wireshark does not mention FTP)? How and under which circumstances does the device get updates? If the device is downloading the update e.g. from a website there is no need for an open port on the device since it does not run a network service itself. Also firewalls often block incoming but not outgoing connections.

Comment: @secfren It is DJI drone which uses FTP to upgrade firmware. First its assistant software downloads firmware from its CDN website and than it uses FTP protocol to transmit it to the device using USB. How do I know? because in previous version of devices FTP port was open and you could monitor packets transferring from Computer to device using wireshark. But in this version you can see that it creates a Host with particular IP - 192.168.42.3 (in our case) . This IP is always same. by scanning this IP using nmap you can see Host is up but it shows all ports are closed.

Comment: When it uses USB, how does it transfer data? Via network (usb-to-ethernet) or directly via USB? In the latter case you won't see any open ports, nor lots of packets on the ethernet interface. You'd need to capture on the USB port. Was the Wireshark dump captured during firmware download to the device? Transferred amount of bytes seems rather small ... You could try to disassemble the firmware and look if it still has software for ftp or if an ftp or firewall service is enabled. Maybe they just removed ftp (if it is not used for updates). https://github.com/o-gs/dji-firmware-tools

Comment: https://www.nozominetworks.com/blog/dji-mavic-3-drone-research-part-1-firmware-analysis/ "because in previous version of devices FTP port was open and you could monitor packets transferring from Computer to device using wireshark. " Packets? Or complete firmware upgrades?

Comment: @secfren Actually first firmware is transferred into the drone and then Drone itself unzip or untar the firmware (Because Firmware bin is compression of multiple modules). After unzipping, it decrypts the firmware. If you go by this than you can say it transmit whole firmware in single transmission and not packets.

Comment: If it does via network and ftp then this should be visible via Wireshark. But your txt (pcap would be better) does not show anything like that. How do you know the update was previously done via ftp over network? Just because there was an open port does not mean the update was done that way. Is the txt a capture from a real firmware update?

Comment: @secfren Yes this text file doesn't show that it is using FTP to transfer the firmware but there are third part software which are used to upgrade or downgrade the drone. They uses FTP protocol but unfortunately new version of drones are not supported like Mini 3 pro or Mavic 3. https://github.com/jezzab/DUMLdore example of such software is this. And in previous of version drones, by using wireshark you can see that FTP is being used. Commands like Type to set binary mode is used, STOR command is used to store data on host (drone) is used.

Comment: Where is the pcap that shows FTP is used (during firmware upgrade) *and how do you know that this is still the case*? If new versions still do upgrades via FTP over network then this should be clearly visible during packet capture. If the port is *constantly* closed but still FTP is used then the upgrade should still be visible in a pcap. But the FTP port would be open on the PC and not the drone. Is there any proof that new drones still use FTP or do you just think this is the case because FTP was used in the past? btw according to internet there are multiple IPs. Did you check 192.168.42.2?

Comment: There might be a rare case that the port does not show up because they use a firewall and port knocking but this, + opened port + firmware transfer, should still be visible in captured packets.

Comment: @secfren Here is the example that FTP is used by previous drones to transfer firmware to the drone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wZHBPssEak I do not have pcap of previous drones but this video will show you how it works. I do not know how it is transferring firmware in this drone (Mini 3 pro), I can't think beyond FTP tbh. I tried some USB sniffer software to check if it is transmitted through USB serial port but it uses Bulk usb and even after sniffing each usb, there is nothing.

Comment: @secfren Is it possible that while opening the DJI software it triggers the drone to open its FTP port? But even if it possible, we can't see it in pcap file.

Comment: If it is transferred over the network or USB it should be visible somehow in particular when the firmware file is rather big. Either Wireshark or simply the number of transferred packets. What USB sniffing software did you use? It should be possible with Wireshark, too. As what kind of hardware (multiple?) does the drone come up when plugging in (or during upgrade)? Did you check during an upgrade or just while plugging in?